# Swift: Find Realm Object in Array

Tags: swift, realm

How to find an object from realm array of object, for example i have object like this:

```
var employee :Array<CWEmployee> = []
```

i need to find the employee where the name for example "Mike". I try like this but it gave me an error:

```
var single = realm.objects(self.employee).filter("name = 'Mike'")
```

Thanks

Comment: If you want people to help with your error, don't you think it might be a good idea to describe the error?

Answer (score 2):

There's no Realm class named `Array`; the only classes Realm provides with that collection behavior are `List`, `Results`, and `LinkingObjects`.

In this case, I'm assuming that's a standard Swift `Array` and `CWEmployee` is a Realm `Object` subclass that you've manually placed in there yourself.

Either way, you're using `realm.objects()` incorrectly. `objects()` requires the class reference itself as the argument; not an object instance.

If you wanted to find all employees named Mike in your Realm file:

```
let allMikes = realm.objects(CWEmployee.self).filter("name = 'Mike'")
```

If your `employee` property contains manually filtered `CWEmployee` objects, and you want to further filter that to find Mike, you should be able to use Swift's `Array.filter` method to do that.

```
let allMikes = employee.filter { $0.name == "Mike" }
```

Let me know if you need any further clarification.